# Cannot find module 'lodash/_overRest'

Tags: npm, lodash

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and downloading it again through npm command but nothing works.

I'm getting:

> Cannot find module 'lodash/_overRest'

I am using npm ver 5.2 and have uploaded the screenshots of the errors and json file

[image: Screenshot of error]
[image: screenshot of package.json]

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {
  ObjectID
} = require('mongodb');

var {
  mongoose
} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {
  Todo
} = require('./models/todo');
var {
  User
} = require('./models/user');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/todos', (req, res) => {
  var todo = new Todo({
    text: req.body.text
  });

  todo.save().then((doc) => {
    res.send(doc);
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});

app.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
  Todo.find().then((todos) => {
    res.send({
      todos
    });
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});

app.get('/todos/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;

  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }

  Todo.findById(id).then((todo) => {
    if (!todo) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.send({
      todo
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});

app.delete('/todos/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;

  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }

  Todo.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((todo) => {
    if (!todo) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.send({
      todo
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});

app.patch('/todos/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['text', 'completed']);

  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }

  if (_.isBoolean(body.completed) && body.completed) {
    body.completedAt = new Date().getTime();
  } else {
    body.completed = false;
    body.completedAt = null;
  }

  Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    $set: body
  }, {
    new: true
  }).then((todo) => {
    if (!todo) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.send({
      todo
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started up at port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = {
  app
};
```

Comment: I think I managed to untangle this with my edit.

Comment: @jasonAller thanks for the edit.. I am so lame ...to put any question correctly on stackoverflow,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated the lodash module to the latest ver. and now it's working pretty fine!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think we are facing the same problem with the same tuto of Andrew about node js. Just upgrade or install the latest version lodash 4.17.5 it will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day. I have all the versions exactly as in Andrew's tutorial, but only this upgrade works. I'm wondering how is that possible.

Comment: No problem. we may help each other to fulfill this good tuto :)

Comment: Thanks for the help @wass but I sorted it out by myself..See guys the problem is the ver of modules he has used, that has been deprecated (many of them). It's hard for the beginner to tackle with such situation.